# Is there an ingame way to change volume?

Tags: destiny

I like the music, but I still prefer my own music.

Is there an ingame way to change the volume?

I can't find it.

Comment: This isn't in yet, but it needs to be! Can't stand Peter's silly flat emotionless voice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2fye3j/why_is_there_no_ingame_way_to_change_the_volume/) topic there isn't. At least for now.

Answer (score 1):

But audio adjustment for the music is coming in a pending patch:

http://www.playstationlifestyle.net/2015/03/20/destiny-update-1-1-2-to-include-audio-volume-settings-colorblind-mode/