# Can you turn off the music in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

I'm wary to even call it music. It's just a bunch of racket.

I should be fair: the cinematic stuff is truly great. Just that dubstep when the big battles are happening.

Can I at least *lower* the volume?

Settings include

- Logout
- Brightness
- Screen Bounds
- Voice
- Look/Move
- Button Layout
- Look Controls
- Subtitles

I've never seen a game without Audio settings...

Comment: Have you checked the settings?

Comment: Yes, of course I've checked the settings.

Comment: @Ben not a duplicate this is purely asking for the music where as the other question was about overall volume.

Comment: @Flaunting *"I like the music, but I still prefer my own music"*. It's definitely related. And as Mathias suggested below, the answer is the same for both questions, because it's related to the same thing. I see it as a duplicate, you don't, no harm done really?

Comment: Ok it is related but that is asking about volume not just muting it all together and to be honest this question is better worded.

Comment: Someone should edit that question title to "Is there an in-game way to change the volume in Destiny?" so it's actually useful. I wouldn't have opened this question otherwise.

Comment: @naomik Duplicates work just like that.  Now the answer is in 1 place, but people asking the question have 2 points of entry with different keywords.

Answer (score 2):

As I answered [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183668/is-there-an-ingame-way-to-change-volume/183669#183669), there is currently no way to change the ingame's audio. So also not turning off the music, unfortunately. It is indeed ridiculous there isn't such an option, and hopefully they will fix it.